# ListCtrl - wxPython get all the values from a column

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to get all the values(items) in a *wx.ListCtrl* column as a list?

I can see in the documentation that you can get a specified item, but not the whole column, `GetValue()` do not work either, any help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Subject')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Due')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Location', width=125)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Get Column 0")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getColumn)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_line(self, event):
        line = "Line %s" % self.index
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "01/19/2010")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "USA")
        self.index += 1

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getColumn(self, event):
        """"""
        count = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
        for row in range(count):
            item = self.list_ctrl.GetItem(itemId=row, col=0)
            print item.GetText()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Personally, I like ObjectListView better than ListCtrl.

Comment: What version of wx.Python has ObjectListView?

Comment: It's not part of wx currently. You can find it on PyPI though: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ObjectListView

Comment: is possible to get them in a list?? like `['Apple', 'Ball', 'Cat']`

Comment: Yeah. Create a list in the getColumn method and add each item to the list.